# Using R object in DBgetquery

Tags: sql, r

How do i use an R object in a DBgetquery ?

example

i have some selected ids in R as topIds
topIds=c('a','b','c'......)

i want to query details of only these topIDs

```
query =dbgetquery(conn, " SELECT AGE , NAME  
                          FROM table 1
                          where ID= paste0('topIds') )
```

how do i put topIds R object into the query to fetch my info  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a brief list of variables (in Oracle less then 1000 keys) you may use `paste`

For numeric key simple paste with delimiter `,`

```
> numLst <- c(1,2,3)
> paste('select * from T where id in (',paste(numLst, collapse=','),')')
[1] "select * from T where id in ( 1,2,3 )"
```

For character key you must additionaly quote the strings:

```
> charLst <- c('a','b','c')
> quotedLst <- mapply(paste0, "'", charLst, "'")
> paste('select * from T where id in (',paste(quotedLst, sep="'", collapse=','),')')
[1] "select * from T where id in ( 'a','b','c' )"
```

If you have a large number of keys you may put them in a database table first (check `dbWriteTable` or `sqlSave`) and constrain the key direct in the DB query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to collapse topIds and paste0 it into the query, something like this

```
ids_for_query <- paste0(topIds, collapse = ',')
query <- paste0("SELECT AGE , NAME
FROM table 1 where ID IN(", ids_for_query, ")", sep = '')
```

You might however encounter a problem if topids is very large